# how to select a specific list item from a ul javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that adds list items that all have the same id to a ul. I want to be able to click a specific list item and change the id of only the one I clicked.

so I'll call the function a few times and have it spit out:

- thing1
- thing2
- thing3

then when I click thing2 the color changes from black to red.

edit: in response to request for the code I tried.

```
function addlist(){
  var ask = prompt("what is the list item", "title");
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML += "<li id='vid'><a href='#'>" + ask+ "</a></li>";
```

}

Comment: Please post the code you tried!

Comment: You shouldn't have a bunch of html elements with the same `id` property.

Comment: You shouldn't have two and more items with same id, so if you want them to have same color, use class.

Comment: As previous comments about `id` and you have to make your question more clear by regarding some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dynamically create the list items, as others have pointed out, you should give them different `id=""`. I am assuming you could implement a solution where you ensure a unique ID and add an `onmousedown` attribute onto each `<li>`.

### HTML

This assumes you add the `onmousedown` attribute to each `<li>` and have given each item a specific ID.

```
<ul>
    <li id="theone" onmousedown="changeColor(this.id)">Click 1</li>
    <li id="thetwo" onmousedown="changeColor(this.id)">Click 2</li>
    <li id="thethree" onmousedown="changeColor(this.id)">Click 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript

```
function changeColor(id) {
    //Do whatever you want to the specific element
    var listitem = document.getElementById(id);
    listitem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/t8xfeL0p/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same id. Instead give them all the same class. http://jsfiddle.net/anw66zu7/4/

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li class="black">One</li>
   <li class="black">Two</li>
   <li class="black">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
//when window loads

  var blackelements = document.getElementsByClassName("black");
// get all elements with class "black" 

  for(var i=0; i < blackelements.length;i++) {
//create a for loop to go through each of these elements.
//the variable i increments until it reaches the amount of elements
//stored in the variable blackelements 

      var blackelement = blackelements[i];
//get the element with the index of the variable i

    blackelement.addEventListener("click",  function() {
//add an event listener to this element that checks for a mouse click

    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
//if clicked change the background color to red.

    });
//close out of the event listener
  }
//close out of the for loop

}
//close out of the onload function
```

Basically what happens is that it looks for all elements with the class "black" - it then loops through them and adds an event listener that looks for the "click" event to each of them. When you click it changes the background color of that specific item "this" to red.

Comment: From how I understand it, he's creating the list items dynamically after loading the page.

Comment: Right, but as we've pointed out, he should not use the same ID. If he needs help changing the appended list items from the same ID to the same class I'd be happy to help, but it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

First, your `<li>`s need to contain buttons to click and `onclick` call a function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="functionName(this)">Thing1</input>
```

In the function, you will call on the object and use the `id` function to change the id and the `backgroundColor` to change the color:

```
function functionName(obj)
{
obj.id = "new id"
obj.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

Comment: An element can be clicked perfectly fine without a button.